# Font button in Attribute Inspector broken?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, osx-yosemite

When I click on the ´T´ button in the Font attribute, the sub menu doesn´t appear. I´m talking about this button:

[image: T button]

The button on the far right of the Font attribute. The sub menu won't appear no matter what I do. I closed Xcode, uninstalled and installed it again without any success.

I'm using OS X Yosemite and Xcode 6.1.1.
I had this problem on OS X Mavericks with Xcode 6.1.1 as well.

Does any one have this issue as well?

Comment: Have you tried restarting XCode?

Comment: _I closed Xcode, uninstalled and installed it again without any succes_

Do you think actually think restarting will help if re installing didn't help?

Comment: For me, it works when short-clicking on it. If the click takes a little bit too long, the popup won't appear...

Comment: its is a bug, sometime my xcode crashs when click on **T**

Comment: OMG! @anneblue, thank you. I can't believe Apple would time a click on a button. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a question about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when short-clicking on it. If the click takes a little bit too long, the popup won't appear.